# Neo4j - Cypher: How to get random pairs of permotations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes of type A and nodes of type B.
I want to match X nodes of A and Y nodes of B and create relationship between all those A's and all those B's

Was I tried so far was (X=2, Y=2):

```
MATCH (a:A) WITH a,rand() AS rand1 ORDER BY rand1 desc LIMIT 2
MATCH (b:B) WITH a,b,rand() AS rand2 ORDER BY rand2 desc LIMIT 2
CREATE (a)-[i:IN]->(b)
RETURN a,i,b
```

But that only create 1 connection for each selected A and B.
For example:

```
a1-IN->b1  
a2-IN->b2
```

I want to get to a point where I create all permutations:

```
a1-IN->b1  
a1-IN->b2
a2-IN->b1  
a2-IN->b2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-foreach.html This should help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
MATCH (a:A) WITH a, rand() AS rand ORDER BY rand LIMIT 2
WITH collect(a) AS as

MATCH (b:B) WITH b, rand() AS rand ORDER BY rand LIMIT 2
WITH as, collect(b) AS bs

UNWIND as AS a
UNWIND bs AS b

CREATE (a)-[i:IN]->(b)
RETURN a,i,b
```